# Proof concerning specific class of Proth numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-verification

Is this proof acceptable ?

**Theorem**

Let  $N = k\cdot 2^n+1$  with  $n>1$ , $k<2^n$ , $k$ odd  and  $3 \nmid k $ , thus

$N$ is prime iff $3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod N$

**Proof**

Necessity : If $N$ is prime then $3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod N$.

Let $N$ be a prime , then according to  Euler criterion :

$3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv \left(\frac{3}{N}\right) \pmod N$

If $N$ is  prime then $N \equiv 2 \pmod 3 $ and therefore : $\left(\frac{N}{3}\right)=-1$ .

Since $N \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $ according to the law of quadratic reciprocity it follows that :  $\left(\frac{3}{N}\right)=-1$ .

Hence , $3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod N $ .

Sufficiency : If $3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod N$ then $N$ is  prime.

If $3^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod N$ then according to Proth's theorem $N$ is  prime .

Comment: If $N$ is prime couldn't it be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ as well?  Also does $3$ have to be a quadratic non-residue if $N$ is prime?  I don't think Proth's Theorem expects $3$ to always be a quadratic non-residue.  It just needs the existence of some quadratic non-residue of $N$:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this proof acceptable ?

I think it is acceptable.

For necessity : I found nothing wrong in your proof. I think that it might be better to add an explanation about how to get $N\equiv 2\pmod 3$, but your proof is acceptable.

For sufficiency : You can apply Proth's theorem here, so your proof is acceptable.